# Concatenate in R (equivalent of COALESCE when using sqldf)

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I'm trying to create an audit report, which takes call-log data [Table 1] and compares it to timesheet data [Table 2]. I need a simple query to return 'OK' if there is record of call log data [Table 1] that matches timesheet data [Table 2].

Table 1

```
Date            Project Code    Amount  Employee
11/2/15         30018           250     Tom Thompson
11/2/15         30018           500     John Johnson
11/2/15         20018           500     Jane Doe
```

Table 2

```
Project Code    Project Name    Employee       Hours    Dates
30012           A               Jane Doe       4        11/2/15
3200            B               Jane Doe       2        11/2/15
4               C               Jane Doe       1        11/2/15
20018           D               Jane Doe       1        11/2/15
4               C               John Johnson   6        11/2/15
```

I'm using the sqldf package in R, running the following:

```
test2 = sqldf("
    SELECT a.*,
    CASE
        WHEN
            a.Name = b.employee and a.Date=b.Dates AND
            a.Project like b.ProjectCode
        THEN 'Okay'
        ELSE 'Flag'
        END 'Audit'

    FROM Table_1 as a, Table_2 as b
    WHERE a.Name = b.employee
    GROUP BY a.Name
")
```

This does not return what I need. Mantaining SQL logic I'd like to concatenate Table 2 (or group by) to yield:

```
Project Code            Employee    Dates
30012, 3200, 4, 20018   Jane Doe    11/2/15
```

My thinking is that I can then use a "like" statement in the case statement above and it will work.

Comment: I don't get the role of the first table. Can't you get your output without using `Table_1` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired outpu in base R with `aggregate` and `paste`:

```
aggregate(Project_Code ~ Employee + Dates, data=df, paste, sep=",")
      Employee   Dates          Project_Code
1     Jane_Doe 11/2/15 30012, 3200, 4, 20018
2 John_Johnson 11/2/15                     4
```

There are a couple of other functions that will return this result. As @nicola mentions, you could also use `toString` to achieve this. Another option is `c`.

```
aggregate(Project_Code ~ Employee + Dates, data=df, c)
```

Which looks the the result above.

---

Note, however, that the structure of this data is more complicated than first appears. Here is the result of using `str` on the output with `c`:

> 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
>    $ Employee    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Jane_Doe","John_Johnson": 1 2
>    $ Dates       : Factor w/ 1 level "11/2/15": 1 1
>    $ Project_Code:List of 2
>     ..$ 1.1: int  30012 3200 4 20018
>     ..$ 1.2: int 4

So the program code variable is actually itself a list. If this is an issue, you could use `paste` with the `collapse =", "` argument to have it return a single string variable, which looks more or less identical:

```
aggregate(Project_Code ~ Employee + Dates, data=df, paste, collapse=", ")
      Employee   Dates          Project_Code
1     Jane_Doe 11/2/15 30012, 3200, 4, 20018
2 John_Johnson 11/2/15                     4
```

But has a simpler structure.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="Project_Code  Project_Name    Employee    Hours    Dates
30012           A               Jane_Doe       4        11/2/15
3200            B               Jane_Doe       2        11/2/15
4               C               Jane_Doe       1        11/2/15
20018           D               Jane_Doe       1        11/2/15
4               C               John_Johnson   6        11/2/15")
```

Comment: You can use `toString` directly instead of `paste`.

Comment: Is `toString` more efficient in some way?

Comment: For the programmer it is, since you save some keystroke :) Joking aside, guess it's less efficient, but can be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Using `R`, we can do a `left_join` between the two datasets, then grouped by 'Employee', 'Dates', `paste` the 'ProjectCode' (`toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=', ')`)

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(Table_2, Table_1, by = c("ProjectCode", "Dates" = "Date", "Employee")) %>% 
    group_by(Employee, Dates) %>%
    summarise(ProjectCode = toString(ProjectCode))
 #     Employee   Dates           ProjectCode
 #        <chr>   <chr>                 <chr>
 #1     Jane Doe 11/2/15 30012, 3200, 4, 20018
 #2 John Johnson 11/2/15                     4
```

As @nicola mentioned, we can get the output using only 'Table_2' alone

```
 Table_2 %>%
      group_by(Employee, Dates) %>%
      summarise(ProjectCode = toString(ProjectCode)) 
 #    Employee   Dates           ProjectCode
 #        <chr>   <chr>                 <chr>
 #1     Jane Doe 11/2/15 30012, 3200, 4, 20018
 #2 John Johnson 11/2/15                     4
```

#### data

```
 Table_1 <- structure(list(Date = c("11/2/15", "11/2/15", "11/2/15"), 
 ProjectCode = c(30018L, 
 30018L, 20018L), Amount = c(250L, 500L, 500L), Employee = c("Tom Thompson", 
 "John Johnson", "Jane Doe")), .Names = c("Date", "ProjectCode", 
 "Amount", "Employee"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

 Table_2 <- structure(list(ProjectCode = c(30012L, 3200L, 4L, 20018L, 4L), 
ProjectName = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "C"), Employee = c("Jane Doe", 
"Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "John Johnson"), Hours = c(4L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 6L), Dates = c("11/2/15", "11/2/15", "11/2/15", 
"11/2/15", "11/2/15")), .Names = c("ProjectCode", "ProjectName", 
"Employee", "Hours", "Dates"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I guess that you can save the `join` part... I don't get what's the purpose of the first table.

Comment: @nicola I am a bit confused by the first table.

Answer (score 1):

The description, input, output and code in the question are all inconsistent (e.g. the code refers to Name input and Audit output columns but neither appear in the input and output shown) so we have assumed the inputs in the Note at the end, the columns shown in the output in the question and modified the code to address the inconsistencies and to use `group_concat`.

There may be other problems with the code but would need more clarification on the intent to address those, particularly with respect to whether the Audit column is supposed to be calculated even though not apparing in the sample output and, if so, exactly what it represents and what the reference to coalesce in the subject refers to.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT group_concat(b.ProjectCode) as 'Project Code', a.Name, b.Dates
              FROM Table_1 as a
              JOIN Table_2 as b ON a.Name = b.employee
              GROUP BY a.Name")
```

giving:

```
                 Project Code         Name   Dates
1          4,3200,20018,30012     Jane_Doe 11/2/15
2                           4 John_Johnson 11/2/15
```

**Note:**  These inputs were assumed:

```
Lines1 <- "Date            Project    Amount  Name
11/2/15         30018           250     Tom_Thompson
11/2/15         30018           500     John_Johnson
11/2/15         20018           500     Jane_Doe"

Lines2 <- "ProjectCode    Name    Employee       Hours    Dates
30012           A               Jane_Doe       4        11/2/15
3200            B               Jane_Doe       2        11/2/15
4               C               Jane_Doe       1        11/2/15
20018           D               Jane_Doe       1        11/2/15
4               C               John_Johnson   6        11/2/15"

Table_1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE)
Table_2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 b WHERE a.Name = b.employee)
             THEN 'Okay'
             ELSE 'Flag'
        END) as Audit
FROM Table_1 a;
```

Comment: thanks, Gordon! And that will work if there are multiple entries on the same date? I.e. multiple projects on one date, if one of them hits then 'okay'?

Comment: This is fine if there are multiple rows in `b`.